# Programmatic sort functionality not working in Tabulator

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I am having an issue with `Tabulator` and its programmatic sorting capabilities.  More specifically, the `setSort()` function is not working as anticipated when invoked by the `tabEndNewRow` method.

The following is my `Tabulator` table setup code:

```
    var table = new Tabulator(divId, {
        height: "100%",
        data: [],
        layout: "fitDataFill",
        tabEndNewRow: function (row) {
            table.setSort([
                { column: "DateComp", dir: "asc" },
                { column: "TimeStart", dir: "asc" }
            ]);
            return { DateComp: currentDate, TimeStart: "6:00 AM", TimeFinish: "6:00 AM" };
        },
        columns: [
            { title: "Date Worked", field: "DateComp", responsive: 0, hozAlign: "center", sorter: "date", editor: dateEditor },
            { title: "Start Time", field: "TimeStart", responsive: 0, hozAlign: "center", sorter: "time", editor: timeEditor },
            { title: "Finish Time", field: "TimeFinish", responsive: 0, hozAlign: "center", sorter: "time", editor: timeEditor }
        ]
    });
```

I am trying to re-sort my `Tabulator` table each time I insert a new row using the `tabEndNewRow` method.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/aklaver/yaqwp04r/35/

It works once you move to the next row.  If that is not what you want then you may have to do the setSort() somewhere else in the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are having is because you are sorting the table and then returning the new row, so the new row is always applied after the sort.

You will need to add a `setTimeout` to delay the sorting until after the row is added:

```js
tabEndNewRow: function (row) {
    
    //delay sorting until after the new row is added
    setTimeout(() => {
        table.setSort([
            { column: "DateComp", dir: "asc" },
            { column: "TimeStart", dir: "asc" }
        ]);
    }, 100);

    return { DateComp: currentDate, TimeStart: "6:00 AM", TimeFinish: "6:00 AM" };
},
```